# Angular5: how to highlight certain dates in mat-datepicker?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular5

i am trying to pre-select some dates in mat-datepicker (angular 5) the problem here that i can't use [dateClass] directive because its an angular 7 feature

```
<mat-form-field>
<input matInput [min]="dispoStartDate" [max]="dispoEndDate" [matDatepicker]="picker" >
<mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
 <mat-datepicker [dateClass]="dateClass" #picker startView="year" >
</mat-datepicker>/mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 2):

According to angular material documentation (https://material.angular.io/)
if you want to highlight specific dates in the calendar you can do so with the `dateClass` input. It accepts a function which will be called with each of the dates in the calendar and will apply any classes that are returned. The return value can be anything that is accepted by `ngClass`.

HTML:

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker [dateClass]="dateClass" #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

TS:

```
dateClass = (d: Date) => {
    const date = d.getDate();
    return (date === 1 || date === 20) ? 'example-custom-date-class' : undefined;
}
```

CSS:

```
.example-custom-date-class {
  background: orange;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
```

If you want to select a specific date, you can use eg. `FormControl`

HTML:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker1" placeholder="Angular forms" [formControl]="date">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker1"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker1></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>`
```

TS:

```
date = new FormControl(new Date());
```

Comment: hi, i got some issues here, https://stackoverflow.com/q/56076337/8662236

Comment: I have some date list like: 
`datelist:any=[
    {
      date:'2021-11-09T14:00:00.000Z'
    },
    {
      date:'2021-10-08T14:00:00.000Z'
    },
    {
      date:'2021-12-19T14:00:00.000Z'
    },
    ....
  ]`
Now how can I activate the date into the select date picker based on the back-end dynamic date? It's will be really help for me if you have answer.

Comment: See example: https://stackblitz.com/run?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdatepicker-value-example.ts Just use eg. `<input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker3" [value]="date.value">`

Comment: You can also define `formControl` for datepicker input

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue, but with date-range-picker. I could tell that the `dateClass` callback was working because I logged a message to the console from the callback. Yet, the styles I was applying did not show up in the calendar.
The Solution:
make sure you include:

```js
import {ViewEncapsulation} from "@angular/core"/; 


@Component({
  selector: 'app-doughnut-chart',
  templateUrl: './doughnut-chart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./doughnut-chart.component.scss'],
  encapsulation:ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

Notice the import of ViewEncapsulation and the encapsulation property in the @Component decorator's configuration object.

When I made sure to include that, it fixed the problem for me.