# Active date picker date with dynamic date which providing from back-end

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-daterangepicker, angular-material-datetimepicker

Frind's. I have a simple Angular application with the material date picker. In this application some data providing from the back-end. Now I do like to active the date picker date, based on the back-end dynamic data(which date has data). The below link is solve my problem partially but not fully solved the problem.

`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55987412/angular5-how-to-highlight-certain-dates-in-mat-datepicker`
[image]

The above link solves the problem by activating 2 specific dates as hardcoded, But I want it should be the dynamically active all date, which date has data into the back-end.

Hopefully, someone experienced person will fix this problem and help me to complete my project successfully.

Comment: you could use `<mat-datepicker  [startAt]="date" #picker></mat-datepicker>`. `date` is assigned `onInit` via a call to your backend..

Comment: **HTML** `<mat-date-range-picker #picker [dateClass]="dateClass"></mat-date-range-picker>` and **TS**  `dateClass = (d: Date) => {
    const date = d.getDate();
    return (date === 6 || date === 20) ? 'example-custom-date-class' : undefined;
  }` I am using like this way.